# Trying to get the user to hit enter to generate the next prime number

Tags: java

I am attempting to have the user press enter in order for the next prime number to be generated. After the user has generated the amount of primes they need, they will enter 0 in order for the program to end. Currently, the program just spits out all of the numbers until it hits the limit, and i need it to only print a number when the user presses enter, or end when they enter 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(!input.hasNextInt(0));    
        for(int i=2; i<=1000; i++){ 
            for(int j=2; j<=i; j++){ 
                if(j==i){
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                if(i%j==0){
                    break;
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: where is the issue statement in your question??

Comment: the program only spits out all of the numbers at one time, instead of waiting until the user presses enter. Also if the user does not hit enter and they enter in 0, the program will need to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your outer for-loop is iterating completely from 2 to 1000 before the next while-loop check. When you try to break the for loop with `if(i%j==0)`, you're just breaking the `if`

Here's a revised version that works and demonstrates what I mean. Note that I also followed the recommendations of the other answers for better form: close your Scanner, and don't use `.hasNextInt(int)`

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++) {
        String next = scanner.nextLine();
        if(next.equals("0")){
            return;
        }else{
            for(int j = 2;j<=i;j++){
                if(j==i){
                    System.out.println(j);
                }else if(i%j==0){//if j is divisible by i...
                    i++;         //try the next i, so we don't print a blank line
                    j=2;         //and reset j
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **semicolon** after 'while(!input.hasNextInt(0))' and try debugging from there. That semicolon is nullifying the while loop. Instead, replace it with an opening brace:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    while(!input.hasNextInt() && !(input.nextInt() == 0)) {    
        for(int i=2; i<=1000; i++){ 
            for(int j=2; j<=i; j++){ 
                if(j==i){
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                if(i%j==0){
                    break;
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Also, best practice to close resources (Scanner) when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

input.hasNextInt is not checking if the entered value is 0. For that, you would want -

```
while (input.nextInt() != 0) { ... }
```

-except that you want to make multiple checks, so you want to save the next input. Perhaps something like

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("First scan: ");
    String next = scanner.nextLine();
    while (!("0".equals(next))) {
        if (next.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Next prime");
        } else {
            System.out.println("String: " + next);
        }
        System.out.println("Next scan: ");
        next = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
    scanner.close();
}
```

This is a quick test I whipped up. We now loop so long as the next input variable is not 0. scanner.nextLine() will submit even if the use enters a blank line (in other words, if they just hit enter).